# Enable/Disable ToolTips for all controls in wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I am writing a WPF application which has a lot of different controls, each with its own `ToolTip`.  Although the `ToolTips` are useful, some of them are quite long and get in the way.

I want to be able to create a button which will enable and disable all the tooltips on the app when it is clicked. what I've been working on seems like a really long and unnecessary way of going at is.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want in a quick manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to add an implicit style that sets the `Visbility` property of all `ToolTips` to `Collapsed` for all top-level windows. Something like this:

```
private bool _isToolTipVisible = true;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Style style = new Style(typeof(ToolTip));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed));
    style.Seal();

    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (_isToolTipVisible)
        {
            window.Resources.Add(typeof(ToolTip), style); //hide
            _isToolTipVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            window.Resources.Remove(typeof(ToolTip)); //show
            _isToolTipVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when I disable the tooltips but when I try to re enable them on the second button click I get an error that says `item has already been added. key in dictionary: 'system.windows.controls.tooltips' key being added:  'system.windows.controls.tooltips'  `

Comment: The error is occurring at this line in the above code `window.Resources.Add(typeof(ToolTip), style); //hide`

Comment: Ensbles them doesn’t add the style. It removes it. You need to set the _isToolTipVisible as per my example.

Comment: I got rid of the `foreach` loop in the code, then put `this` where `window` was and I was able to toggle the tooltips.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add global tooltip style into application resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

This disable all tooltips.

To toggle use following:

```
Style _style;

void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_style == null)
    {
        _style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources[typeof(ToolTip)];
        Application.Current.Resources.Remove(typeof(ToolTip));
    }
    else
        Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(ToolTip), _style);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have custom tooltips that could be turned off. The other solutions didn't quite cover this, so here's what I ended up doing...

This code allows you to have your customised tips, and to easily turn them on and off application-wide. In my case, I'm saving the tool-tip visibility in a user setting. The setting is applied on main window load and then updated if the setting is changed.

In *App.xaml*:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" Background="PaleGoldenrod" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ... various other settings
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NoTip" TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Style>
```

Then, in my *MainWindow.xaml.cs* (but could go wherever you are changing the tip visibility):

```
private Style styleWithTips;
private Style styleNoTips;
...
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set initial tips on/off
    styleWithTips = (Style)Application.Current.Resources[typeof(ToolTip)];
    styleNoTips = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["NoTip"];
    updateTipStyle();
}

private void Settings_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "ShowHints")
    {
        updateTipStyle();
    }
}
...
private void updateTipStyle()
{
    ResourceDictionary resources = Application.Current.Resources;
    bool showHints = Properties.Settings.Default.ShowHints;
    if (resources.Contains(typeof(ToolTip)))
    {
        resources.Remove(typeof(ToolTip));
    }
    resources.Add(typeof(ToolTip), showHints ? styleWithTips: styleNoTips);
}
```